# upgrading my project from ruby 1.8.7 to 2 and Rails 3.2.3 to 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a Rails project made in ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.2.3. Some previous developers started it in 1.8.7 and 3.2.3 about a year and a half ago. It was made completely for desktop - mobile looks terrible. I'd day there's about 60,000 - 90,000 lines of code in the project (is there a way to count this? I use Sublime)

It turns out, the application is much more useful on mobile. I had thought the common sense thing to do would be to create mobile views/ tweak what we have/ add some new features...so it looks good on mobile phones.

But my new developer who I have been working with has thrown his hands up and says now he insists I upgrade to Ruby 2 and Rails 4. Which means most of the project is going to have to be written again.

Has anyone experience of upgrading from 1.8.7 to 2 and 3.2.3 to 4? It is a huge job? Can I not just keep what I have or would that cause headaches down the road? Just interested in your ideas, thanks....

Comment: Is there a way to count lines of code? Approximate with `find` and `wc -l`. I'm sure a lot of people have had experience upgrading Ruby and Rails, but this isn't really a great SO question.

Comment: you can run `rake stats` for code statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade from 3.2.x to 4 is not that painful for a seasoned RoR dev. There are a few tutorials and sites about the pains, but fairly minimal.

Unless you are using some gem that is no longer available/updated on 3.2.x then I would probably stay there. Many gems are not rails 4 compatible yet.

Now after saying that. It is always good to keep your app up to date. This will save you time/money in using new and updated gems and finding programmers that can/will work on it as time goes on.

Comment: Thanks.any tips on going from 1.8.7 to 2. I hear 1.8.7 is old, old, old.if I'm going from 1.8.7 to 2 might I as well go to rails 4 also?

Comment: 1.8.7 is fairly old. I would venture to guess that MOST of the app out there are on 1.9.3 which is still receiving patches.

Comment: The main problems I remember on 1.8.x to 1.9.x revolve around character encoding. 1.8.x does not care about the encoding of documents (source code and db records is your main concern), where 1.9.x does.
I would probably make two steps 1.8.x to 1.9.3 and then 1.9.3 to 2.